# Mikro in Mikrofon/Mikrophon

Tags: meaning, etymology

Phon/Fon steht für: *Stimme, Klang, Laut, Ton*. Aber worauf bezieht sich das "Mikro" (*klein*) im "Mikrofon"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The always very useful "Etymonline" website has this:

**microphone** (n.): 1680s, "ear trumpet for the hard-of-hearing," coined from Greek mikros "small" (see mica) + phone "sound," from PIE root *bhā- (2) "to speak, tell, say" (see fame (n.)). Modern meaning dates from 1929, from use in radio broadcasting and movie recording. Earlier, "amplifying telephone transmitter" (1878). Of the two spellings of the short form of the word, mike (1927) is older than mic (1961).

Damit wäre ein frühes Mikrophon eigentlich ein Hörrohr. In das man möglichst direkt hineinsprach, um dem fast tauben Großvater etwas mitzuteilen. Und da man auch in ein modernes elektrisches Schall-zu-Strom-Umwandler-Gerät direkt hineinspricht, nannte man auch dies praktischerweise ein Hörrohr. Oder Mikrophon.

Hier noch eine ergänzende Vermutung: Die ersten Schallaufzeichnungsgeräte waren ja nicht elektrisch. Vielmehr wurden Schwingungen mit einer Nadel in einen rotierenden Zylinder mit Wachsüberzug geritzt. Der Schall wurde aufgefangen (und in Nadelschwingungen verwandelt) mit einem... eben: Hörrohr (ähnlich dem Schalltrichter des Grammophons). Damit wären Großvaters Hörrohr und das erste Schallaufzeichnungs-Mikrophon nicht nur "zweckgleich" sondern sogar praktisch baugleich.

Comment: Das ist interessant, weil es auch hier um den Aspekt der Verstärkung zu gehen scheint. Die Frage ist nur, ob die moderne Verwendung nicht eine unabhängige Neuschöpfung ist. Trotzdem schon mal +1

Comment: Ich hab mal bei https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Carbon_microphone#History_of_the_term_.22microphone.22 und bei https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion:Microphone#Histoire_du_terme nachgefragt; beide Seiten behaupten, dass die moderne Bedeutung auf Hughe zurückgeht; mal sehen, ob da jemand eine Quelle nachreicht...

Answer (score 0):

Die Entwicklung des Mikrophons hängt eng mit der Entwicklung des Telefons zusammen. Die ersten Schall-Rezeptoren an den Telefonen von Philipp Reis und Elisha Gray wurden noch als *transmitter* ("Überträger") bezeichnet.

Nach [en:wikipedia *Carbon microphone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_microphone)

> Hughes' device used loosely packed carbon granules - the varying pressure exerted on the granules by the diaphragm from the acoustic waves caused the resistance of the carbon to vary proportionally, allowing a relatively accurate electrical reproduction of the sound signal. **Hughes also coined the word microphone.**

übereinstimmend mit [Hugh Robjohns: *A brief history of microphones*](http://microphone-data.com/media/filestore/articles/History-10.pdf):

> The modern term of 'microphone' also appears to have been coined by Hughes. (S.2)

stammt der Begriff *Microphone* in seiner heutigen Bedeutung von David Edward Hughes (1831–1900). Gemäß der letzten Quelle haben zeitgenössische Zeitungen den Begriff von Hughes als Analogiebildung zu *Microscope* verstanden:

> He [Hughes] demonstrated his transmitter by mounting it on a sound box containing insects whose scratchings were then perceived to be 'amplified'. Reports in the newspapers suggested that the device ‘...acts for the ear much in the same way that the microscope serves the eye, hence its name’. [S. 2]
>
> *Er führte seinen Transmitter [die bis dahin übliche Bezeichnung der Mikrophone von Reis und Bell] vor, indem er ihn auf einer Schachtel mit Insekten anbrachte, deren dann wahr und verstärkt wurden. Berichte in den Zeitungen behaupteten, dass dieses Gerät '... dem menschlichen Ohr in der gleichen Weise dient, wie das Mikroskop dem Auge - daher der Name'.* [Übersetzung von mir]

Beide Quellen sind freilich nicht wirklich zitierfähig. Die etymologischen Wörterbücher, die ich konsultiert habe - [Pfeifer: *Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Mikrofon), Kluge: *Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache*, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/microphone), Robert: *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* - geben leider nichts her.

Ich halte die Erklärung für plausibel, aber das heißt in etymologischen Fragen ja noch nicht viel. Vielleicht finden sich mit diesen Hinweisen ja noch weitere Belege, deswegen schreibe ich das hier schon mal als Antwort.

Comment: Das *wäre* plausibel, wenn das Wort "Mikrophone" nicht schon im 17. Jahrhundert in Frankreich für's "Hörrohr" gebraucht worden wäre.

Comment: @tofro Das ist nicht notwendigerweise ein Widerspruch. Es könnte sich um eine unabhängige Neuerfindung handeln.

Comment: @tofro Das passt schon zusammen. Nach den Beschreibungen wurden bei den "Transmittern" zur Bündelung des Schalls Trompeten und Schnecken verwendet, die genau so aussahen und funktionierten wie die Höhrrohre, die damals Schwerhörige verwendeten. Die Außenstehenden sahen also hauptsächlich das "Höhrrohr", in das hineingesprochen wurde, und dann war die Benennung wohl naheliegend.